# How do I give MacPorts privileges?

Tags: macos, macports, privileges, postgresql

I tried to install PostgreSQL server development libraries using MacPorts and got the following:

```
Warning: MacPorts running without privileges. You may be unable to complete certain actions (e.g. install).
--->  Computing dependencies for postgresql-server-devel
--->  Dependencies to be installed: postgresql-devel
--->  Building postgresql-devel
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: postgresql-devel
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

So I guess that means I need to running MacPorts *with* privileges and try again. Unfortunately I've no idea how to give MacPorts privileges.

I'm running OS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use `sudo`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

```
sudo port <commands>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea what particular command I should use, or, if you don't know, how I can find out more about to use sudo to grant a particular program privileges?

Comment: @cojadate: Why not use the installer? http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx

Comment: Do you have the `psycopg2` module installed?

Comment: It's all sorted now, so yes I do finally have psycopg2 installed